# Single ActiveRecord collection from two models based on criteria from a third HABTM model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an address book that is made up of `Addresses`, `Businesses`, and `Individuals`. All three models have HABTM relationships, because that's how reality works.

Each address also has geographic coordinates (`Address.latitude` and `Address.longitude`).

I want to get a collection for my Rails controller at a special point (`/london`) that has, in one collection, all of the Businesses *and* Individuals who have an address in London that ends up on a Leaflet map.

But I also *don't* want any addresses outside of London.

Currently,

```
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :addresses, join_table: :addresses_individuals
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses, join_table: :businesses_individuals

  scope :london, -> { joins(:addresses).where("addresses.latitude < ? AND addresses.latitude > ? AND addresses.longitude < ? AND addresses.longitude > ?", $London[:north], $London[:south], $London[:east], $London[:west]).distinct }

  def js_slug
    "#{self.first_name}_#{self.last_name}".parameterize.underscore.camelize(:lower)
  end
end
```

I access in the controller with `@individuals = Individual.london`, and it gives me all of the Individuals who have London addresses, but if someone also has an address outside of London, then it's collected into the list (and ends up on the map if I zoom out).

I made a similar scope for `Address`:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :individuals, join_table: :addresses_individuals
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses, join_table: :businesses_addresses

  scope :london, -> { where("addresses.latitude < ? AND addresses.latitude > ? AND addresses.longitude < ? AND addresses.longitude > ?", $London[:north], $London[:south], $London[:east], $London[:west]) }
end
```

and now,

```
@individuals = Address.london.map{ |a| a.individuals }
```

comes close to what I want, at least in the console, but when I put that into the controller:

```
class Frontend::FrontendController < ApplicationController

  layout :resolve_layout

  respond_to :html

  def london
    @individuals = Address.london.map{ |a| a.individuals }
    # @individuals = Individual.london
    @fitbounds = [[$London[:south], $London[:west]], [$London[:north], $London[:east]]]
    @circle_markers = nil
    render "city"
  end
```

the view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
  <tbody>
    <% @individuals.each do |individual| %>
      <tr>
        <td id="<%= individual.js_slug %>">
          <%= link_to "#{individual.first_name} #{individual.last_name}", [:frontend, individual] %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

errors out and I get:

```
undefined method `js_slug' for Individual::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:Class
```

The call to `js_slug` works fine when I use `@individuals = Individual.london`, but then I get all the addresses that aren't in London on my map.

So without iterating over every address once the collection is made via `@individuals = Individual.london` and throwing out the addresses outside of London, how can I get such a limited set?

Then when I do the same thing with Businesses, how can I merge/join it with the collection of Individuals?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give us, the controller code, the view logic and the Address model (the relation on it)?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to add that to the original question. I changed around the error I'm seeing a bit, as the original error in the view was for a helper that was building some javascript. This is far more basic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Address.london.map{ |a| a.individuals } returns a single element, that is the collection of individuals (try @individuals.count, should be equal to 1).

Essentially what we're after here is all the records in the joins tables where the address_id belongs to an address in London, and we want to show the individuals that belong to the individual_id.  Therefore I think we get get to what you want using a scope in the joins table as follows.

```
# address_individual model (sim for business)
class AddressIndividual < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :london, -> { where("address_id in (?)", Address.london.map(&:id)) }
end
```

We can then call this in the controller.  I would use a different name than 'individuals' to avoid confusion (and we will define the individual in the view below).  I'll just use 'address_individuals'.

```
# individual controller
class Frontend::FrontendController < ApplicationController

  layout :resolve_layout
  respond_to :html

  def london
    @address_individuals = AddressIndividual.london

    @fitbounds = [[$London[:south], $London[:west]], [$London[:north], $London[:east]]]
    @circle_markers = nil
    render "city"
  end
end
```

We can then refer to this in the view, and just need one extra step to show the individual.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
  <tbody>
    <% @address_individuals.each do |ai| %>
      <% individual = Individual.find(ai.individual_id)
      <tr>
        <td id="<%= individual.js_slug %>">
          <%= link_to "#{individual.first_name} #{individual.last_name}", [:frontend, individual] %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think that does it for you.  You can do the exact same thing for businesses.  I'm not sure then how to combine these into a single scope or active record query - I would just do two loops in your view for each.

Comment: That scope currently does 2 queries unnecessarily. Try `joins(:address).merge(Address.london)`

Comment: Thanks. I did this, and now I get multiple entries for people w/ two London addresses _and_ still have dots show up on the map outside of London. With the previous system I had, at least individuals weren't getting duplicated.

Comment: Ok.  Does Address.london work correctly?  Confused as to why AddressIndividual.london wouldn't be, if so.  Unsure as to how the dots on your map relate to the list and how you want this to look - I'm wondering whether it is best to create a separate variable for each?  Your initial individual.london and address.london would do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start from the bottom.

It's the best when the problem is non-existent, right? Instead of looking for a way to merge 2 collections of different models you may ask yourself: is it worth separating them in the first place?

I'm not talking about making them one model, no. I'm talking about Single Table Inheritance, that would effectively allow you to store these two models in one table (by making these two inherit from the model that owns that table, not `AR::Base`). That implies that that single table would need to have the fields of both models and a `type` field. If they're similar already, you'll be fine, if not, it's up to "is it worth it". That would allow you to query the "root model" only if some query could possibly result in having both individuals and businesses: ActiveRecord will instantiate the correct object. And factoring out the common things into the base model is so DRY.

And now for the main problem.

You seem to not have settled on what lists you want in the controller, in the example code you only mention individuals and your complaint basically is that you get unwanted addresses. That is fair, you didn't query for addresses explicitly, instead you're fetching them based on another dataset that doesn't have the conditions it was constructed with. Sounds more complicated than it actually is...

First of all, leave "londoning" to the address model and reference it from other places like so:

```
scope :london, -> { joins(:addresses).merge(Address.london).distinct }
```

Secondly, if you need a list of addresses, query addreses:

```
@addresses = Address.london
```

If you need associated individuals there, when `each`ing you'd get N+1 query problem, bypass it like so:

```
@addresses = Address.london.includes(:individuals)
```

This is pretty much the same code that you have above. Is that not obvious? Okay, how about this snippet from a view (using Slim/HAML for brevity here):

```
- @addresses.each do |address|
  - address.individuals.each do |individual|
    = individual.whatever
```

Absolutely the same except for the second line, since you've already mapped addresses to the collections (not individuals themselves!) in the controller. That's what @FunTimeFreddie is talking about too and he is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think it might make sense to use Single Table Inheritance, which is something I didn't know about. I'll try to incorporate your and @funtimefreddie's suggestions and see what I get. Part of why I'm using the Individual is because the list of individuals is sorted, which is a step I would have to add.